# Socket programming - Java; Port forwarding does not work, it worked before though. Could it be an ISP thing?

Tags: java, sockets, port, serversocket, forwarding

I'm trying to open a `ServerSocket` from behind a router. Forwarded the port correctly. It worked perfectly before but now the port isn't opening (canyouseeme). I checked the firewall and nothing is blocking the port. Tried on both `Linux` and `Windows`. I assume there is something to do with the ISP.
What could be the issue?

The code,

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server
{
    private static final int port = 13370;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket sS= new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("\nListening on port "+port+" ...");
        while(true) {
            Socket s = sS.accept();
                BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                String ip = bufR.readLine();
            File ipF = new File("/root/payload/ip.txt");
            if(!ipF.exists()) {
                ipF.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(ipF.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bufW = new BufferedWriter(fileW);
            bufW.write(ip);
            bufW.close();
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime())+": "+ip);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work on the local host? Does it work on the local network? Have you restarted the router? Have you restarted the gateway device (if applicable)? Are you able to connect out to the internet, and receive packet data back? Does a different port work?

Comment: Yes it works on local network. 
Yeah tried restarting and resetting the router and modem but not helping.
Yep the internet is working fine.
No port is working.

Comment: Then it sounds like your ISP.

Comment: So what can I do to get around it?

Comment: Try a VPN or a different ISP.